# Get a page-referrer full URL (previous URL) in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router

I'm trying to find a way to get a referrer-page (previous) full URL in React app using Route, and can't find appropriate solution in the Web. Here is what I already tried:

`useHistory` doesn't seem to help much, since it only allows to redirect to a URL in its history stack, but there's no way just to access the referrer-page URL.

Same with JS `window.history`.

JS `document.referrer` doesn't seem to be helpful either. It returns a base URL only, no full path.

The full URL is required since some data needs to be accessed from its path and url queries.

Maintaining the value in a global React state might not be a great solution either for the case, because a referrer is not always an internal link.

```
const getReferrerUrl = () => {
  // get the page-referrer URL
  // do logic based on the path and url queries
  // return (logic_results)
}
```

Comment: What is your app being referred from? Something external to the app? A page within the app?

Comment: In most cases it is referred from within the app using Routes and I need the URL in a component. In some other cases it is referred from another Angular SPA.

Comment: Within the app you'll typically just grab the current `location` object, i.e. `const location = useLocation()`. Not sure off the top of my head how to handle external navigations *other than* encoded in a queryString parameter or similar.

Comment: useLocation gives an access to the current URL only. I need something similar, but for a previous URL

Comment: Correct. You grab the current location, to be used as the referrer, ***before*** you redirect within your app, i.e. so it's the previous location when landing on a page that cares what the previous location was so it can get back to it.

Comment: There are many possible scenarios to end up on the page even within the app. That's why it might be too many places where I would need to pass the value. I can create Redux state for that, but was looking to avoid the global state management for the value. Also it wouldn't work for external links anyway

Comment: I keep a history stack in my redux state so I can simply query where I've been *within* my app. You're correct about the external links. The trick here is allowing your app to know how it was loaded, i.e. was it loaded by directly typing the URL in the address bar, or was there a navigation action from elsewhere. If all you have is the current URL in the address bar what can you do? Maybe the server serving up your app can capture a referrer from the requester?

Comment: Yea, I guess I might end up having to implement Redux and involve back-end as well. Was wondering if there was an easy way to access the referrer, but apparently there isn't one. Thanks for your help anyway @DrewReese